# SHOULD I remove stock internet app on galaxy J5 2015?

Tags: rooting, samsung, bloatware, samsung-galaxy-j5

I have rooted my samsung galaxy J5 (2015), but I am not sure whether or not I should remove the preinstalled "Internet"-app. The phone came with both that AND google chrome, and so the question is whether it's a good idea or not to remove it in order to free 50+ MB of storage on a phone that only has an 8GB total.

Comment: The app resides in the system partition. Removing it will not give you 50MB of space back in your data partition. It'll give you only a few MB at most.  If you don't know if removing a system app will break anything or not, then don't remove it.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove it without any problems but i would recommend to flash a custom "lite" rom the is debloated even more depending on you model number of the J500